# Icons similar to desktop shortcuts inside JDesktopPane

Tags: java, jdesktoppane

As we are using **JDesktopPane** with **JInternalFrames** for our software, I am wondering if we can have Shortcut Icons (to particular Frame) placed inside the desktop pane (Similar to Windows desktop shortcuts). I searched for this but no luck.

Any idea guys to make this happen??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is **not** a "good" solution, but maybe OK-ish for certain application cases. The main difficult is that the central class that comes into play here is [`JInternalFrame.JDesktopIcon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.JDesktopIcon.html), and the documentation of this class contains a

### Warning:

> This API should NOT BE USED by Swing applications, as it will go away in future versions of Swing as its functionality is moved into JInternalFrame.

However, the corresponding functionality in `JInternalFrame` simply is not there. And although one has to accept that the `JDesktopIcon` class *might* be removed in future versions, it seems very unlikely for me, considering the broad usage of this class in the internal Swing UI implementations.

However: One option to achieve this is to create a custom extension of the `BasicDesktopIconUI`. Fortunately, this class handles most of the janitorial work, like dragging support and un-iconifying the frame on double clicks.

As a result, one can easily sneak custom icons into such an implementation (I only used a placeholder here: A red cross on a black background. But it can be an arbitrary `Image`.)

[image: Internal Frame Icons]

This is implemented here as a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The general UI handling may be different in an actual application, but the basic idea is to create the custom UI class and assign it to the internal frame icons.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicDesktopIconUI;

class SimpleDesktopIconUI extends BasicDesktopIconUI
{
    private final Icon icon;

    SimpleDesktopIconUI(Icon icon)
    {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    @Override
    protected void installComponents()
    {
        frame = desktopIcon.getInternalFrame();
        String title = frame.getTitle();

        JLabel label = new JLabel(title, icon, SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
        label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);

        desktopIcon.setBorder(null);
        desktopIcon.setOpaque(false);
        desktopIcon.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        desktopIcon.add(label);
    }

    @Override
    protected void uninstallComponents()
    {
        desktopIcon.setLayout(null);
        desktopIcon.removeAll();
        frame = null;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize(JComponent c)
    {

        LayoutManager layout = desktopIcon.getLayout();
        Dimension size = layout.minimumLayoutSize(desktopIcon);
        return new Dimension(size.width + 15, size.height + 15);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(JComponent c)
    {
        return getMinimumSize(c);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMaximumSize(JComponent c)
    {
        return getMinimumSize(c);
    }
}

public class InternalFrameIconTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGUI());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Icon icon = new ImageIcon(createImage());

        JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            String title = "Test " + i;
            if (i == 2)
            {
                title = "Test 2 with longer title";
            }
            JInternalFrame internalFrame =
                new JInternalFrame(title, true, true, true, true);
            internalFrame.setBounds(20 + 50 * i, 300 - 40 * i, 160, 80);
            internalFrame.setVisible(true);
            desktopPane.add(internalFrame);

            internalFrame.getDesktopIcon().setUI(new SimpleDesktopIconUI(icon));
        }

        f.getContentPane().add(desktopPane);
        f.setSize(600, 600);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static BufferedImage createImage()
    {
        int w = 50;
        int h = 50;
        BufferedImage image =
            new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawLine(0, 0, w, h);
        g.drawLine(0, h, w, 0);
        g.dispose();
        return image;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good approach but as icons are just minimized bar so closing the JInternalFrame making the whole thing disappear. I will try to minimize the internal frame on close action. Maybe then Icons will stick there. Good solution.

Comment: There are different options to achieve this. The easiest would be to make the internal frame non-closable (change the second `true` in the constructor call to `false`). Beyond that, this could probably be disucssed in a dedicated question **if** there isn't already one about this topic.